# Markup for download link between paragraphs

Tags: html, html4

What is the recommended way to markup a single download link between paragraphs of text? I currently use the *blockquote* element:

```
<blockquote><a href="...">...</a></blockquote>
```

but I have read that it should only be used for quotations. Should I simply use a *p* element instead (and indent with CSS)?

Answer (score 1):

It definitely isn't a blockquote.

It probably isn't a paragraph.

It might be most appropriate to use a plain div element.

Answer (score 0):

As either a `p` or a `blockquote` will work, you can use either. However, if the text you want to `mark up` is a paragraph and not a blockquote, then the `p` tag is more appropriate. HTML tags are meant to be semantic description of the text's mark up.

Comment: As pointed out by Quintin, semantically it's nor a quotation neither a paragraph; it's more like a single element list.

Answer (score 0):

`<a href="link to pdf" download="book.pdf">Download the book</a>`

Add the download attribute would be great. But between `p` and `blockquote` the `p` tag would be the best (for semantic)

Comment: I'm using HTML 4 (XHTML), so the *download* attribute is not available.

Answer (score 0):

[Blockquote](https://www.w3schools.com/Tags/tag_blockquote.asp) is for a longer quotation (HTML4) or a quotation from another source (HTML5).

It sounds like the link is a part of a larger body of text, like an article, and in that case I would put it in a `p` tag